# How do I make a split in a sphere for a robotic elbow/knee joint?

Tags: modeling, mesh

[image]I thought I had to select the middle loop and scale it but it looks weird

[image]

[image]

I want to give my robot some joints, it's just for detail and how he moves.

Comment: Hello, please show what you've done, you can scale a middle loop, you may need to activate the Proportional Editing option

Comment: There are numerous way to do this, with different outcomes. Can you please provide more specific examples of what you're trying to do?

Comment: i want to give my robot some joints, it's just for detail and how he moves. im gonna add a pic of him

Comment: Any reason why you have a solidify modifier on the sphere?

Answer (score 1):

Select middle line, scale it down.
[image]

Select both boundary lines in a circle and bring them closer

[image]

apply "bevel" to these same lines

[image]

subdivide, and aplly "shade smooth"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Start with a UV Sphere then in Edit mode:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Back in Object mode, this is the result with just a Subdiv Surface modifier:

[image]